# Construction of a meromorphic extension.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the  connected set $\Omega \subset \{z \in \mathbb{C}:  Re(z) > 0\}$ we define  $\Omega^+\equiv\Omega \cap \mathbb{C^+}\neq \varnothing  $ and $\Omega^-\equiv\Omega \cap \mathbb{C^-\neq \varnothing } .$

Now we define the analytic function $f(z)$ in $\mathbb{C^+} \equiv \{z \in \mathbb{C}:  Im(z) > 0\}$

Suppose we have a function $g(z,\theta)$ defined for  $ \theta \in D \equiv \{y \in \mathbb{C}: \mid y \mid <1\}$ and $Im(z)>0$ with the condition:

1. it is at least meromorphic in $\theta$ for fixed $z_0 \in \Omega^+$ and $\theta \in D \cap \mathbb{C^+}$
2. for $\theta\in \mathbb{R} $ we have $f(z)=g(z,\theta)$.
3. for fixed  $\theta_0 \in D_\epsilon ^+ \equiv$
   $\{y \in D : Im(y) > \epsilon\},$ $g(z,\theta_0)$ can be meromorphic extended in $z$ to the region  $\Omega^-_\epsilon \subset \overline{ \Omega^-} .$

I want to construct a mermorphic extension of $f(z)$ in the region 
$\Omega^-_\epsilon$. My idea is this:

For $\theta\in \mathbb{R}, $ $g(z,\theta)$ is analytic in $\theta$ .Now if we fix $z_0 \in \Omega^+$  we have that the function $g(z_0,\theta)$
   for $ \theta \in D$ is a a mermorphic extension of $g(z_0,\theta)=f(z_0)$ in $\theta$ when $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$, by 1. So $g(z
,\theta)$ for fixed theta is a meromorphic function of $z$ for $z \in \Omega^+.$

Now we fix  $\theta_0 \in D_\epsilon ^+$ than by 3 there is a meromorphic extension $h(z)$ of $g(z,\theta_0)$ in the region $\Omega^-_\epsilon$.

Now if we proof that $g(z,\theta )$ is constant in $\theta$ than $h(z)$ would be a meromorphic continuation of $f(z)$.
Is $g(z,\theta )$ is constant in $\theta$ ?

Comment: Your question is impossible to understand

Comment: Why it is impossible